# Cannot call a pure virtual function in its abstract class?

Tags: c++

I have a code which is similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>

class parent
{
public:
    parent()
    //does initializations here
    {
        start();
    }
    virtual void start()=0;
}

class child :public parent
{
public:
    child()
    {}
    void start()
    {
        std::cout << "starting.." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Calling the `start()` function in the constructor of parent class causes a **linkage error** *(unresolved external symbol)*. I thought this wouldn't be a problem, why does it? Is there an alternative way rather than calling the `start()` function manually after construction?

Comment: You're calling methods on the derived object before the object is fully constructed

Comment: After posting the question I found a similar question on right side of the page(i don't know why the search didn't yield those results)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual dispatch only works to parts of the object that have been constructed already. In `parent`'s constructor, `child` does not yet exist, so calling `start()` calls `parent::start`.

You can provide a body for it by doing:

```
void parent::start() {}
```

although to achieve the call of `child::start` you would need to call it from `child`'s constructor.